# Dimension of Kernel of Matrix

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix. If there is a non-zero real vector $x$ such that for all $y$ satisfying $Ay=0$, then $y=kx, k\in \mathbb R $.

i) What is the dimension of Ker(A)

ii) Explain why the columns of A are linearly dependent.

i) Is ker(A) $n \times 1 $ dimensional as $\exists x \ \forall y | Ay=0 $, there are $n$ rows of $y$ for the multiplication of matrices to be valid, and since for every $y$ there's a unique vector then the number of columns is $1$.

ii) Since $\exists y | Ay=0 $ and $y\neq 0 $ then clearly it's linearly dependent by definition.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer to ii) is correct and complete.

Your answer to i) is incorrect, and it is difficult to understand what you are trying to convey with your explanation. The answer is that $\ker(A)$ is a $1$-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^n$. One justification of this answer is that the set $\{x\}$ (which contains one element) forms a basis of $\ker(A)$.

Comment: How did you deduce that {x} is one dimensional though since it is a vector? SInce $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix then $y$ must be an $n \times 1 $ matrix and since $y=kx$ I deduced that $x$ must also be $n \times 1 $.

Comment: @Smirniy007 $\{x\}$ is not "one dimensional" or even "$n$ dimensional" by the definition we are using here because it is not a subspace. It seems that you don't understand what exactly "dimension" means in this context; I recommend that you check your notes or textbook.

Comment: oh my bad, just realised dimension was the number of vectors in the basis, confused it with something else, cheers!